# Insert Data into HashMap - Race condition

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I am working on a Spring Webflux application in which I need to make 1 Spring webflux call for each document to a Document Storage system.So 20 documents will make 20 calls.The calls happen fine and I am able to get back data as well. Issue arises when these 20 calls come back and want to populate a  single HashMap which is of the below mentioned structure.

//DocumentType is an Enum

HashMap<DocumentType,List> = new HashMap();

So every document will go in the List based on its document type. I have written the below mentioned code for this

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ///here uploadFiles is the final Map I want to populate
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(uploadedFiles);
    Type type =
        new TypeToken<Map<DocumentType, List<FileUploadDetailsDTO>>>() {}.getType();
        //this is the cloned uploadFiles to avoid get and put on the same HashMap and cause ConcurrentModificationException
    Map<DocumentType, List<FileUploadDetailsDTO>> clonedUploadedFiles =
        gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);

       //I do a get from the cloned Map always
      if (clonedUploadedFiles.containsKey(DocumentType.make(documentType))) {
        List<FileUploadDetailsDTO> clonedFilesForDocTypeList =
            new ArrayList<>(clonedUploadedFiles.get(DocumentType.make(documentType)));
        clonedFilesForDocTypeList.add(fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO);
        //and only put in the original map always
        uploadedFiles.put(DocumentType.make(documentType), clonedFilesForDocTypeList);
      } else {
        List<FileUploadDetailsDTO> listOfDocuments = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfDocuments.add(fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO);
        //and only put in the original map always
        uploadedFiles.put(DocumentType.make(documentType), listOfDocuments);
      }
```

**Problem**: Sometimes it causes a race condition and 2 threads which put into the HashMap at the same key since they satisfy the first if condition which does a **containsKey** check on the Map.

**Options Tried**:

A) **ConcurrentHashMap**: But it does guarantee prevention of ConcurrentModificationException but does not guarantee that elements are inserted correctly.I have tested and concurrenthashmap does not populate all the elements all the time correctly

B) **Synchronised** :Used synchronised on the uploadFiles map above but that defeats the purpose of using spring webflux

Comment: Why do you want to write to the hashmap concurrently? Cant you use a Queue to write values to the hashmap for simplicity? Which means push the messages into the queue first and write to the Hashmap by popping from the queue

Comment: Why not just use synchronization? In the context of uploading files any attempt to improve on it is futile.

Comment: thanks @NavaneethSen and user207421 Now I have aggregated above 
 fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO objects into lists such that even if multiple threads try to PUT into the HashMap, they will always do the PUT at different KEYS. So, even if 4 threads are modifying the HashMap with PUT they will do so at 4 diff Keys at any given time. I am not doing a GET at all now since there will be no value corresponding to the key present in the HashMap when I do a PUT.  Would it still cause ConcurrentModificationException? From what read it occurs when you are iterating and updating via multiple threads

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier I tried multiple options like below:

A) **ConcurrentHashMap**: But it does guarantee prevention of ConcurrentModificationException but does not guarantee that elements are inserted correctly.I have tested and concurrenthashmap does not populate all the elements all the time correctly

B) **Synchronised** :Used synchronised on the uploadFiles map above but that defeats the purpose of using spring webflux

C) **Deep Cloned** the HashMap and made sure I am GETTING only on the cloned map and PUTTING only to the original map but then I faced race condition

Since I was using **Spring webflux**, the approach which finally worked for me was to aggregate the threads using **collectList()** after the call to the DocumentStorage and then group them based on the attribute which was going to be used as the key in the final hashmap in question. **I did this so that I dont have to iterate over the hashmap and insert at the same time. All I did was just PUT making sure that there are NO multiple PUTS for the same key**

Code to aggregate the threads returning from the DocumentStorage.Please read the comments as well :)

```
Flux.fromIterable(entryValue)
                  .flatMap(
                      fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO -> {
//call to the documentStorage happens at per document level
                        return callToDocumentStorage(fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO);
                      })
                  .collectList()
                  .flatMapMany(
                      fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTOS -> {
                      //final grouping by key happens here
                        groupByKeyAndInsertToMap(
                            fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTOS);
                        return Flux.fromIterable(fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTOS);
                      });
```

The groupingBy and insert code in above function groupByKeyAndInsertToMap() goes like this:

```
 Map<String, List<FileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO>> groupedByDocumentType =
        fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTOs.stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                    fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO -> {
                      return fileUploadLodgeReturnDetailsDTO.getDocumentType().name();
                    }));
  //the final PUT into the MAP at unique Keys Always to avoid ConcurrentModificationException
    groupedByDocumentType.entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(
            stringListEntry -> {
              uploadFileList.put(
                  LandDocumentType.make(stringListEntry.getKey()),
                  new ArrayList<>(stringListEntry.getValue()));
            });
```

This solution can be helpful for non spring webflux applications as well where you just collect the objects into a List and group them by the parameter which is going to be the key in your final HashMap